# Embeding Sigend data with pdf using iText

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have a encoded signed data in a string (" >MIILwwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIILtDCCC7ACAQExDzANB........ ")

And I need to combine it with the pdf for signatures.

I am using following code

```
public class MyExternalSignatureContainer  implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
 protected byte[] sig;
 // String b64String;

    public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig) {
    this.sig = sig;
}

@Override
public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary arg0) {
}

/**
String PKCS7Resp = "MIILwwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIILtDCCC7ACAQEx.........;
Base64Encoder b = new Base64Encoder();
    byte[] signedData = b.decode(PKCS7Resp.getBytes());

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:\\AADHAAR.pdf");
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("D:\\AADHAAR1.pdf");

    ExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedData);
    MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, "}", os, external);

 *
 * @param arg0
 * @return
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 */
 @Override
public byte[] sign(java.io.InputStream in) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException{
      Base64Encoder b = new Base64Encoder();
        byte[] signedData = b.decode(PKCS7Resp.getBytes());
       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:\\AADHAAR.pdf");
      FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("D:\\AADHAAR1.pdf");          
      ExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedData);
         MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, "}", os, external);
         }
          }
```

but its showing error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: No field
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDeferred(MakeSignature.java:246)
at test.MyExternalSignatureContainer.main(MyExternalSignatureContainer.java:131)
  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

In line

> MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, "}", os, external);

Reference code

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("my_private_key.pfx"), "my_password".toCharArray());
String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, "my_password".toCharArray());
Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("original.pdf");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("signed.pdf");
PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, '\0');
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
sap.setCrypto(key, chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
sap.setReason("I'm the author");
sap.setLocation("Lisbon");
// comment next line to have an invisible signature
sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1, null);
sap.setExternalDigest(new byte[128], new byte[20], "RSA");
sap.preClose();
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
byte buf[] = new byte[8192];
int n;
InputStream inp = sap.getRangeStream();
while ((n = inp.read(buf)) > 0) {
   messageDigest.update(buf, 0, n);
}
byte hash[] = messageDigest.digest();
PdfSigGenericPKCS sg = sap.getSigStandard();
PdfLiteral slit = (PdfLiteral)sg.get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
byte[] outc = new byte[(slit.getPosLength() - 2) / 2];
PdfPKCS7 sig = sg.getSigner();
Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
sign.initSign(key);
sign.update(hash);
sig.setExternalDigest(sign.sign(), hash, "RSA");
PdfDictionary dic = new PdfDictionary();
byte[] ssig = sig.getEncodedPKCS7();
System.arraycopy(ssig, 0, outc, 0, ssig.length);
dic.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(outc).setHexWriting(true));
sap.close(dic);
```

Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: And can anyone tell what will be the value of fieldname?

Comment: You say you *have a encoded signed data in a string* and *need to combine it with the pdf for signatures.* have you had prepared the pdf beforehand and created the signed data matching that prepared pdf?

Comment: Actually we are integrating with another SERVER which asks for pdf hash and details of the user and returns a XML with a PKCS7 response which contains encoded data. I have to  use this response to sign the pdf(whose hash I sent to them) using this response.

Comment: They said that it will be done using iText

Comment: It is impossible for `"}"` to be the `fieldname`. When you say *I have a encoded signed data in a string "MIILwwYJ..."*, you act as if this data is at all times identical for a specific PDF. That isn't true. There will always be data that will be different. We don't see you using an `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer` anywhere to prepare the PDF for signing. You claim: *they said that it will be done using iText*, but who are *they*? Do they have a commercial license to use iText? If so, contact premium support for help. If they are using iText under the AGPL, ask them to publish their code.

Comment: We are integrating with company, who provides the service of Digital signature on documents with the verification of user's identity. we provide them document hash and the user's identity data in a XML and they returns a response which is a PKCS7 response contains signed data. And I have to embed this data with document.

Comment: As the document is pdf we have to use iText ( suggested by that company ). When I asked that we need some certificate to use iText.

Comment: They told that "In the given reference code,  they are loading keystore with private key because they are also doing procedure of signing in the same code but here you already have a signed data(PKCS 7 response) which you have to decode  and  embed in your document. So, write your code accordingly with taking help of reference code"

Comment: I will add the reference code with question

Comment: Should I add the response XML, which contains PKCS7 encoded signed data?

Answer (score 0):

In your first step you create a signature field with an automatically generated name:

```
sap.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200), 1, null);
```

Confer the associated JavaDocs:

> ```
> /**
>  * Sets the signature to be visible. It creates a new visible signature field.
>  * @param pageRect the position and dimension of the field in the page
>  * @param page the page to place the field. The fist page is 1
>  * @param fieldName the field name or <CODE>null</CODE> to generate automatically a new field name
>  */
> public void setVisibleSignature(Rectangle pageRect, int page, String fieldName)
> ```

Later on, though, you act as if the signature field name was "}":

```
MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, "}", os, external);
```

Confer the associated JavaDocs:

> ```
> /**
>  * Signs a PDF where space was already reserved.
>  * @param reader the original PDF
>  * @param fieldName the field to sign. It must be the last field
>  * @param outs the output PDF
>  * @param externalSignatureContainer the signature container doing the actual signing. Only the 
>  * method ExternalSignatureContainer.sign is used
>  * @throws DocumentException
>  * @throws IOException
>  * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
>  */
> public static void signDeferred(PdfReader reader, String fieldName, OutputStream outs, ExternalSignatureContainer externalSignatureContainer) throws DocumentException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException
> ```

Thus, change your code to make those names match, i.e. either use a fixed name you know not to be used by some other form field in the document or query the generated name used by iText using the `PdfSignatureAppearance` method

> ```
> /**
>  * Gets the field name.
>  * @return the field name
>  */
> public java.lang.String getFieldName()
> ```